# Windows 10 keeps trying to connect with ethernet rather than wifi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet

I have a Windows 10 computer with a lan cable connected to other computers using a Switch and that same computer is connected to internet using a Wi-Fi receiver. It has been working fine until today that internet suddenly stopped working. On Chrome I get all kind of error missatges: ERR_INTERNET_CHANGED, DISOCNNECTED, and some common others.

Researching I found that it could be that Windows has the wrong order of connection, and learn that I could disable the 'automatic metric' of tcp/ip4 settings. I did that by putting the wifi to 1 and ethernet to 5, but still didn't work.

I've also tried to bridge both connections, which resulted in internet working, but keep stopping / renabling every few seconds.

I also tried unplugging the lan cable and disabling the ethernet adapter, when I do that, mi wifi keeps getting lost and found... connected and then in a few seconds not connected, and so on.

I really don't know what else I could try and I really appreciate if someone could help me or point me in the right direction.
Ideally I would like my PC to only use wifi to connect to internet, and the ethernet to connect to the other computers in the network.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why?  Windows 10 can and should handle all connections (internet, servers, machines) out of one port. No need to use two ports.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the wireless adapter that has nothing to do with the wired LAN. You said even when you unplug it the same thing continues to happen. You have a hardware issue it sounds like.

Comment: John, I agree with you, unfortunately the router is far away from my computer setup, so I cannot throw a lan cable directly to it. Appleoddity, I considered that option too, but it actually doesn connect to the internet and read wifi networks nearby, it just does that for a few seconds and then it disconnects... and connect again and so on

Answer (score 0):

Alright managed to fix the issue, it was caused by the Asus drivers of my PCI WiFi card.
As soon as I uninstalled the drivers and restarted my computer, everything went back to normal: LAN connection with the other computers work well, WiFi works well (and even another Bluetooth adapter I had works well).